# How to retrieve NameValuePairs in jersy webservice

Tags: android, web-services

I am using the following code in android

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("results", data));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

httpResponse= httpClient.execute(httpPost);
httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

I am using the following code in my application to receive the data from webservice.

```
@POST
@Path("/saveResponseData/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String saveSurveyResponseData(@QueryParam("results") String responseData)
{
    ...................
}
```

But here i am getting `responseData` as null.How i can get that data in my server side.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the request type from client GET or POST?

Answer (score 0):

try to code like this. 
You should check the response for errors first.

```
if(httpResponse!=null)
{
    int statusCode=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(statusCode>=200&&statusCode<=300)
    {
        //ok response
        // fecth the data from
        HttpEntity entity=  httpResponse.getEntity();
        if(entity!=null)
        {
            // fetch data from 
             String responseBody;
            try {
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println("finalResult"+responseBody.toString());

                //parse your data here

            } catch (org.apache.http.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        // printing the response from server/ what error code occor 
        Log.e("Response from server", httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: I am asking handle in the server side.But not in client side

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `@POST`, try using `@FormParam` anotation instead of `@QueryParam`.

```
@POST
@Path("/saveResponseData/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String saveSurveyResponseData(@FormParam("results") String responseData)
{
    ...................
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: actually now we are iterating the data.For every 5 records we are sending a webservice call

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a request through POST on server side, try using @Consumes ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") and no @QueryParam("results"), like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/saveResponseData/")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String saveSurveyResponseData(String responseData)
{
    ...................
}
```

Your respondeData should be something like "results=data", treat it like a String.

Hope this answer your question.